# Tuning a Synthetic Control

Tags: causality, synthetic-controls

I am working on a project that is seeking to use the synthetic control method to estimate the effect of Costa Rica's military abolition on levels of democracy (0-1 interval). I'll attach my code here and plot the time series to demonstrate the initial issue I am having:

```
library(tidysynth)

synth.opto <- latin.am %>%
  synthetic_control(outcome = democracy,
                    unit = country_name,
                    time = year,
                    i_unit = "Costa Rica",
                    i_time = 1949,
                    generate_placebos = T) %>%
  generate_predictor(time_window = 1935:1949,
                     l.gdppc = mean(lgdppc, na.rm = T),
                     l.milspend = mean(lmilspend, na.rm = T),
                     pr = mean(prop.rights, na.rm = T),
                     dist = mean(distribution, na.rm = T),
                     ce = mean(clean.elec, na.rm = T),
                     pol.vi = mean(pol.v, na.rm = T),
                     phys.vi = mean(phys.v, na.rm = T)
  ) %>%
  generate_predictor(time_window = 1935,
                     dem.1935 = mean(democracy)) %>%
  generate_predictor(time_window = 1937,
                     dem.1937 = mean(democracy)) %>%
  generate_predictor(time_window = 1939,
                     dem.1939 = mean(democracy)) %>%
  generate_predictor(time_window = 1941,
                     dem.1941 = mean(democracy)) %>%
  generate_predictor(time_window = 1943,
                     dem.1943 = mean(democracy)) %>%
  generate_predictor(time_window = 1945,
                     dem.1945 = mean(democracy)) %>%
  generate_predictor(time_window = 1947,
                     dem.1947 = mean(democracy)) %>%
  generate_predictor(time_window = 1949,
                     dem.1949 = mean(democracy)) %>%
  generate_weights(optimization_window = 1935:1949,
                   margin_ipop = .02, sigf_ipop = 7, bound_ipop = 6) %>%
  generate_control()

synth.opto %>% plot_trends()
```

[image]

As you can see, the synthetic control does a decent job at predicting Costa Rica's democracy until the years 1946-1949. This isn't unexpected. Prior to Costa Rica's military abolition, a civil war in 1948 preceded it with increasing levels of political violence leading up to the war. Accordingly, I thought I had found the source of the prediction error. However, as noted in the code here, I incorporated variables that should explain this drop in democracy as covariates for the synthetic unit to be trained on (clean election index, physical violence, political violence). Despite incorporating these variables, the prediction error still exists. In fact, it barely improves.

When I inspect the weights, I notice that they overwhelmingly are sourced from two countries, Panama and Chile. The magnitude of the weights hardly changes when I included the violence predictors, which I imagine is part of the reason why these predictors did little to reduce the prediction error (Neither Chile nor Panama experience comparable levels of violence in this 4-year period). Why is this? Should the allocation of the weights not change in response to the set of covariates? Secondly, what is one to do if the source of the prediction error is known, but including covariates that should cover this error does not work? Is the pre-treatment difference between synthetic and real Costa Rica too large in this example to continue with the project?

Comment: If the non-treatment subjects (Chile and Panama) do not experience a comparable change in pol. violence in this 4-year period, I don't see why the synthetic controls would change. Could it be that the synthetic control method simply has its limits - the other countries aren't similar enough to model things this closely? Compared to the drastic change after 1949 the deviations don't look terrible.